# How to convert sqlite to mysql using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite

I have converted sqlite database into mysql.

so then i need convert sqlite+php code into mysql+php code. do you have any document which containing methods to convert sqlite to mysql.

thanks..

***this is my code***

```
<?php

try {
  //open the database
  $db = new PDO('sqlite:cars.sqlite'); //will create the file in current directory. Current directory must be writable

  //create the database if does not exist
  $db->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cars (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, manufacturer TEXT, year INTEGER, price INTEGER)");

  //select all data from the table
  $select = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM cars ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 100');
  $select->execute();

  $out = array(
    'cars' => $select->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
  );
  echo json_encode($out);

  // close the database connection
  $db = NULL;
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
  print 'Exception : ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

***mysql table:cars***

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cars` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `manufacturer` text,
  `year` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `price` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as you are using PDO, just create Mysql PDO object, change this part:

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:cars.sqlite');
```

to something like:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=yourdbname;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'yourdbuser';
$password = 'yourdbpass';
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
```

and you're done. You dont need to change anything other.

PDO is portable connection object, it can be used with several different database. more about PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php

Comment: i added following db connection, $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("error1");
$db=mysql_select_db("decsys",$con) or die ("error2")

Comment: NO !, you are already using PDO. keep use it !. `mysql_connect` and friends is deprecated and will be removed soon. See my updated answer ?

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr.Charlie. you saved my day!!